# Multi Level Combox - MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, multi-level

I have a MySQL table that looks like this
[image]

And I want to create a combobox that looks like this:

```
Hardware (ID 1, Parent 0)
-Child (ID 2, Parent 1)
-Child (ID 3, Parent 1)
--Child (ID 4, Parent 3)
```

As you can see, the main categories have the parent Id = 0, the rest have an id that is associated to the id of the category.

What I was wondering, is if there was a way to do this, directly through a mysql query? If, so, can you give me an example?

I tried a little with some loops in MySQL but I couldn't get it to make sense in my head.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with one combobox?  Is that a requirement?

Comment: It's not an achievement, but It should be possible with mysql I think :9

Comment: Not really, databases return flat datasets when you want a nested dataset.  You could pull all the data as a flat data set and process it afterwards... BUT having three levels in a single combobox like that isn't really good design either.  You'd be better off with three comboboxes that drill down into the detail dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to 3 levels, you can make 2 `LEFT JOIN`s and get all data in one query:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    TRIM(
        CONCAT(
            REPEAT('-',IF(t2.id IS NOT NULL,1,0) + IF(t3.id IS NOT NULL,1,0)), 
            ' ', 
            t1.label
        )
    ) AS label
FROM 
    mytable t1
LEFT JOIN
    mytable t2 ON (t1.parent = t2.id)
LEFT JOIN
    mytable t3 ON (t2.parent = t3.id)
ORDER BY
    IFNULL(t3.id, IFNULL(t2.id, t1.id))
```